# Using Select prop 'isSearchable' with JSX

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-select

I am trying to make my react-select searchable but I have run into a problem. Basically, the label for my options needs to be in JSX since my client wants to see the contact information of a user at a glance. However, I think the Select prop 'isSearchable' only works when the value is a string. This is what my code looks like:

The data I pass into the 'options' prop of Select:

```
const createContactDisplay = (data) => {
    return data.map((contact) => ({
      label: (
        <Contact>
          <p>{contact.value.firstName}</p>
          <p>{contact.value.lastName}</p>
          <p>{contact.value.email}</p>
        </Contact>
      ),
      value: contact.key
    }));
  };
```

I then pass in my filtered contacts as the data above and set the `options` prop of React select to that state.

Any suggestions on what I should do would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Select` from react-select accepts an array of options where each option is an object with a `label` and `value` properties. If you want to use the search function, you need to convert to the option format that `Select` can understand:

```
const options = originalOptions.map((o) => ({
  label: o.contact.value.firstName,
  value: o.contact.value.firstName,
  data: o.contact.value, // to reference custom data field if needed
}));
```

```
<Select options={options} {...} />
```

[image: Codesandbox Demo]

Comment: I see, thank you. Can I use JSX as the value for the label?

Comment: @Imo yes you can, you can use JSX to display whatever you want in each option. Do you have any problem?

Comment: I think i need to use a function where I pass in my data that I set elsewhere and then return it but from my understanding I cant do that, right?

Comment: @Imo you can use `formatOptionLabel` to do that. See my codesandbox demo.

Comment: Oh yes sorry I didn't see the code sandbox, thank you so much!